# Further questions to limit groups and an article of Fujiwara and Sela

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups

I already have asked a question to the following article:

- Koji Fujiwara, Zlil Sela, *The rates of growth in a hyperbolic group*,  Invent. math. **233** (2023) pp 1427–1470, doi:[10.1007/s00222-023-01200-w](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-023-01200-w), [arXiv:2002.10278](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.10278).

There appeared two further questions to it (the page and theorem numbers refer to the preprint version). Both questions refer to page 28 (proof of theorem 4.2). The general assumption is that $L$ is a non abelian limit group over a free group (of rank at least 2). **But I have the same two questions also for the situation that L is not a limit group but a non-elementary hyperbolic group (page 30: proof of proposition 4.3).**

1. On page 28 we have the following sequence of proper epimorphisms:

$L_1 = L * F_t \to L_2 = L * F_{t-1} \to ... \to L_{t-1} = L * F_2 \to L_t = L*\mathbb{Z}\to L_{t+1} = L$

Fujiwara and Sela say that for every index $i$, $1 \leq i \leq t$ there is an approximating sequence of epimorphisms $v_n^i: L_i \to L_{i+1}$ that converges into the limit group $L_i$. Why does such a sequence exist? Maybe the answers of @HJRW to my other question could be helpfull:

[Question to limit groups (over free groups)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454012/question-to-limit-groups-over-free-groups)

2. Further down on page 28 we have the following:

The sequence of epimorphisms $(v_n^1: L_1 \to L_2)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ conveges into
$L_1$. Hence, by proposition 2.3 $\lim \limits_{n \to 
\infty} 
\mathrm{e}(L_2,v_n^1(S_1)) = \mathrm{e}(L_1,S_1)$. The maps $v_n^1$ are proper epimorphisms, and they converge into $L_1$. Hence, the pairs $(L_2,v_n^1(S_1))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ belong to infinitely many distinct isomorphism classes of pairs (of a limit group and its finite set of generators).

My question is why it is not possible that there are only finitely many distinct isomorphims classes? Somehow Fujiwara and Sela give already an answer. They say that this is the case because "The maps $v_n^1$ are proper epimorphisms, and they converge into $L_1$." But I don't see yet why the claim follows from this.

Comment: In your first question, I don't understand whether the claimed sequence $v^i_n$ is supposed to have anything to do with the initially given sequence of epimorphisms. If not, then you can just use my previous answer and take a free product with the identity map on $L$.

Comment: For the second question, if there were only a finite set then the convergent sequence would be eventually constant, and so would converge to $(L_2,v^1_n(S_1))$ for some $n$. Since the limit is also $(L_1,S_1)$, this means that $v^1_n$ is an isomorphism, which contradicts the claim that it's a proper epimorphism.

Comment: I divide my comment into two parts: 1. I am not sure if the claimed sequence is supposed to have anything to do with the initially given sequence of epimorphisms. Somehow it would be plausible to me but maybe it is not necessary. A question to your comment: In the previous answer you said that the argument only works for $n>2$, but here we also need to consider lower dimensions and need approximating epimorphisms $L*F_2 \to L* \mathbb{Z}$ and $L* \mathbb{Z} \to L$?

Comment: 2. Maybe I have also a direct question to your answer but maybe I have found an own solution now: Let us first consider the case that $L$ is a non-elementary hyperbolic group. From proposition 2.3 Fujiwara and Sela deduce $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{e}(L_2,v_n^1(S_1)) = \mathrm{e}(L_1,S_1)$. But I think that one can also apply proposition 3.2 to get that $\mathrm{e}(L_2,v^1_n(S_1)) < \mathrm{e}(L_1,S_1)$. But if we had only a finite set of isomorphism classes we couldn't get  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \mathrm{e}(L_2,v_n^1(S_1)) = \mathrm{e}(L_1,S_1)$. Is that argument right?

Comment: For 1: You're right, you need a more subtle construction to get the final two maps in the sequence. For instance, you need to understand why $L*\mathbb{Z}$ is fully residually $L$. This is a nice exercise you should definitely try to do for yourself.

Comment: For 2: I don't have the paper in front of me, so don't know what Propositions 2.3 or 3.2 say. But the argument looks right.

Comment: 2. (continuation) Now let $L$ be a non-elementary limit group. I think that the same argument works in this case? Because I think that one can apply proposition 2.3 and 3.2 also to the case that $L$ is a non-elementary limit group.

Comment: @HJRW , now I had time to look at the question why $L* \mathbb{Z}$ is fully residually $L$ and why $L*F_2$ is fully residually $L*\mathbb{Z}$. You said that one needs a more subtle construction. But is it also possible to argue in the following way: $L$ is a non abelian limit group/non elementary hyperbolic group and therefore contains a free subgroup of rank 2. For the same reason, $L*\mathbb{Z}$ contains a free subgroup of rank at least 3. And now one can use the same argument you have used to show why $F_n$ is fully residually $F_{n-1}$ for $n >2$. Is this the correct idea?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.